# Did Windows 10 "Spring" Update remove the speaker output from the Taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803

I upgraded to Windows 10 "Spring" update or whatever they call it a couple of days ago. I haven't really used this machine much since the upgrade, this morning I was going to do some work and I was going to play some music and I noticed the sound wasn't working. It is normal sometimes as Windows 10 picks up my second monitor that has audio output and tries to channel it there. I typically solve this by going to the right-hand corner of the Taskbar where there is a little speaker icon and change the output.

Well as I came to find out this morning it was not there...

I went to the Taskbar settings. There is a section that says "Turn system icons on or off" and it shows the speaker and a switch, which is turned on...

Did they take that feature out or is it a glitch? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so it turns out that it apparently was a glitch.

Here is what I did to fix this.

I went to the Taskbar, right-click -> Taskbar settings, On the left menu go to Taskbar, in the settings on the right side scroll down to "Select which icons appear on the taskbar," find the speaker icon that says "Volume," turn it on and off.

That fixed it for me, and I hope it can help someone else as well in the near future =).

Comment: you mean you turned it off then back on?

Comment: No, I should clarify. I turned it off(It was on) closed the settings and the icon came back to my taskbar, so then I went back in the settings and turned it back on, to keep it on.